# Converting a multidimensional array of strings into a multidimensional array of numbers

Tags: python, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, type-conversion

I am trying to convert this array of strings:

```
[['2014', '913', '5.78254241807211', '52.3749951170618', '2014', '1', '2024448.00', '89316.00', '29187.00', '427000.00', '60.00','0'] ['1', '222.2']]
```

into an array that looks the same but is made of numbers because I need to make computations with it.

I already tried `.astype(np.float)` but it gives me the following error:

```
category_array=(category).astype(np.float)    
VelueError: could not convert string to float
```

How can I slove this?

Comment: Use [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) to convert a string to an integer.

Comment: `arr.astype(np.float)` works on my side, are you sure you do not have artifacts in your array which could not get cast?

Comment: Without numpy (?), a single list comprehension works as well: `new_array = [[float(str) for str in item] for item in array]`.

Comment: The only thing that I have done to artifact the array is that my array (category) is a concatenation of other 3 arrays. I used np.hstack for it.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to convert your list of lists to a numpy array.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> list_of_lists = [['1', '1.5'], ['2', '2.5'], ['3', '3.5']]
>>> numpy_array = np.array(list_of_lists)
>>> float_array = numpy_array.astype(np.float)
>>> float_array
array([[1., 1.5], [2., 2.5], [3., 3.5]])
```

Comment: But the only way the original code would have failed to raise an AttributeError on `astype` is if it was already a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with basic python list approach

```
>>> array_str = [['2014', '913', '5.78254241807211', '52.3749951170618', '2014', '1', '2024448.00', '89316.00', '29187.00', '427000.00', '60.00', '0'], ['1', '2']]
>>> array_n = [[float(num) for num in item] for item in array_str]
>>> array_n
[[2014.0, 913.0, 5.7825424180721097, 52.3749951170618, 2014.0, 1.0, 2024448.0, 89316.0, 29187.0, 427000.0, 60.0, 0.0], [1.0, 2.0]]
>>>
```

Comment: Please avoid using `str` as a variable name.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried your code but it still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the float or int method ?

```
    array  = ['2014','913','5.78254241807211','52.3749951170618','2014','1','2024448.00','89316.00' ,'29187.00', '427000.00' ,'60.00'],['1','2','8']]

    floatlist=[[float(str) for str in subarray] for subarray in array]

    print floatlist
```